Leasing vs paying cash for a new EV for an older couple
My spouse and I are in the market for a new EV and are weighing paying cash versus leasing. I've looked at several of the other questions on leasing vs buying, but we have a some peculiarities that might affect the answer.
I'm 68 and my spouse is 73. My spouse does all the driving. We're both in good health, but I feel like we have to be cognizant of the possibility that during the next ten years we might have to give up driving. We bought our current car new, 25 years ago, so we've gotten good value from that despite the rapid depreciation of new cars. I feel like at this stage in our lives a lease would avoid us getting stung by that rapid depreciation. Getting 25 years out of another new car doesn't seem likely at this stage in our life, and given the rapid changes in the EV market.
As an additional note, the cash would come from our conventional IRA so it would probably add about $8000 to our tax bill for 2025.

Consumer Reports

One thing to consider is the tax rebate situation. Leasing companies get the rebate regardless of your income, and subject to fewer parts-place-of-origin / assembly limits. They’ll pass the savings on to the lessee to be competitive. There can be substantial savings to be had on some EVs when leasing.

I think you're overly focused on depreciation as a "cost".  If you keep the car for more than 10 years, then depreciation is not as much of a factor. Depreciation is only realized as a cost when you sell the car. You're paying for depreciation in a lease also, just over time instead of when you sell the car.  The lease payment is based on the expected value when you renew or give up the lease (which includes depreciation), plus interest, plus profit for the leasing company.
If you want to minimize depreciation, then buy a big truck instead, which keep their value for their utility, not because they don't wear down faster.

We bought our current car new, 25 years ago, so we've gotten good value from that despite the rapid depreciation of new cars.

Yes, new cars depreciate rapidly in the first few years, then taper down. But you can "save" that depreciation cost by buying a 2-year-old model instead of brand new.  If you had bought a 2-year-old model at the same time, it would be worth roughly the same amount today after 25 years. There's virtually no difference in a 25-year-old car and a 27-year-old car except for rare "classic" circumstances.

the cash would come from our conventional IRA so it would probably add about $8000 to our tax bill for 2025.

So, your choice is paying tax now (cash) or paying interest over time (lease), and to "pay" for depreciation upfront (cash) or over time (lease).
Another option - buy a cheaper used car that won't cost you so much in interest or taxes. You can find incredibly reliable 2-year-old cars with low mileage for 2/3 or less of what they cost new.

In this case: OP paid full price to drive a car for 25 years. He could have paid 40% less for a two year old car he could have driven for 23 years. Let someone else pay for the pleasure of owning a brand new car.

Probably Buy
I know someone who leased and EV because they were worried about "the rapid changes in the EV market" ... and at the end of their lease they bought a new EV.
The only thing that's changing quickly about the EV market right now is the battery tech, and it is perfectly possible to switch out the battery on an EV.
There's a Tesla Model S out there with over 1 million miles on it - they've changed the battery a couple of times. (they're probably supercharging a lot, which does lower the batter life more than regular charging.)
So it's perfectly reasonable to buy an EV and have it last for 10+ years.
But Get the Tax Credit
The bigger question is probably if you can get the tax credits - they require certain levels of built in the USA that not all manufacturers are meeting those requirements. Doing a little homework to take $3,500 or $7,000 off the price is a worthwhile investment.
There was a loophole where all EV leases qualified, even if the sale would not have. If that loophole hasn't been closed, and the model you want doesn't qualify for the tax credit as a sale, then that might mean the lease is worth it.

A car lease is mostly meant for companies who own a car for a few years only. If you want this car for a long time buying is cheaper. And buying two years used is cheapest.
I’d look careful if an EV car is best value for money. If you expect low mileage any savings for fuel will also be less.
If you pay $8,000 tax for cash from an IRA, you can pay a lot of interest for that. When you buy ask for a cash price, a price with a loan, and ask your bank about the cost of a loan, then find someone trustworthy who can check what’s best for you. And the lowest cost is a cheaper car.

Unless you are using the car for business, I would pay cash. The leasing company  is making a profit on the deal and you are paying for that profit.
You wrote:
I feel like at this stage in our lives a lease would avoid us getting stung by that rapid depreciation.
My response:
The leasing company is aware of the fact that cars rapidly depreciate. The will set the monthly lease payment accordingly. As such, you will be paying for the depreciation whether you pay cash or lease.
Also, will an EV last ten years? My feeling is that it is likely that the batteries will go in about 6 years and the replacement cost will be very high.

"Also, will an EV last ten years? My feeling is that it is likely that the batteries will go in about 6 years and the replacement cost will be very high." That actually sounds like a reason to lease.

@CharlesE.Grant Assuming the batteries will go in 6 years, the leasing company knows this, and they will set the lease payment accordingly.

8 years is pretty standard for EV battery warranties, regardless of the shorter bumper-to-bumper warranty (similar to how emissions equipment usually has a 7 or 8 year warranty).
